# How to add data in jagged array in typescript?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, push

I wanted to add data in someArray[][] where some data expected is like - [["xyz",123,1.23],["abc",234,2.34],etc]. I've declared someArray and initialized it as - `someArray: any[][] = [[]];` When I'm trying to push into someArray using for loop, I'm getting error as - 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')'. I'm trying to push like this - `someArray[i].Push(property1, property2,etc)` using for loop. Can someone suggest how to push into this jagged array?

Comment: try this: `someArray[i]?.push`

Comment: This worked for me -> I initialized the array in for loop (someArray[i] = []) and then did a push() onto it

Answer (score 0):

You are creating multi dimensional Array there for you need to specify each of the `rows` and `columns` before entering values to the multi dimensional array.

> Please find the working attached stackblitz [here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-html2canvas-fzghrl?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**In component.ts :**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  private someArray: any[][];

  constructor() {
    this.someArray = [];
    this.printArray()
  }

  printArray() {
    for (var i: number = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      this.someArray[i] = [];
      for (var j: number = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        if (j == 1) {
          this.someArray[i][j] = 'XXX';
        } else {
          this.someArray[i][j] = 'ZZZ';
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.someArray));
  }
}
```

**in component.html :**

```
<h4>Sample multi dimensional array</h4>
<p>
  <b>{{ someArray | json }}</b>
</p>
```